# Bootstrap 4 form-group with two pairs of labels and inputs per row

Tags: bootstrap-4

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/tmrczk/pen/yvppZE).

The first form has two pairs of labels & elements laid out on the same row.

What I would like to do is to nest each pair of `<label>` and `<div>` in their own containers: `div.myFormColumnLeft` and `div.myFormColumnRight`.

The problem is that labels and elements in **FORM2** are no longer on the same line.

**QUESTION**. Is there a way to make **FORM2** look exactly like **FORM1** with a slightly different markup?

Comment: A snippet here hasn't worked out?

Comment: check over this https://codepen.io/romeojathu/pen/vYXmRpQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the `d-flex` class to the columns would do the trick in this case:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <b>FORM1:</b>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row">

            <!-- Left column -->
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <!-- Right column -->
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" class="form-control">
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
    <hr />

    <b>FORM2:</b>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row">

            <!-- Left column -->
            <div class="myFormColumnLeft col-md-6 d-flex">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Right column -->
            <div class="myFormColumnRight col-md-6 d-flex">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors

Comment: Thanks! Where in the docs could I find explanation of this trick? How would I know that `d-flex` class is required?

Comment: Here's the link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors